# Is there any reason not to use Hofmann-Streicher universes?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, type-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a small category, and consider the topos $Psh(\mathcal C)$ of $Set$-valued presheaves on $\mathcal C$. For simplicity, assume that there exists a proper class of inaccessible cardinals. If $\kappa$ is an inaccessible exceeding the size of $\mathcal C$, a *universe* of size $\kappa$ in $Psh(\mathcal C)$ is supposed to roughly be an object $U_\kappa \in Psh(\mathcal C)$ such that morphisms $X \to U_\kappa$ correspond to maps $Y \to X$ with $\kappa$-small fibers.

There is some subtlety here having to do with ensuring that the the universe is a (strict!) functor $\mathcal C^{op} \to Set$. But Hofmann and Streicher observed (in an [unpublished note](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/%7Estreicher/NOTES/lift.pdf) (that's a direct link to a 4-page pdf)) that there is a very natural way to construct such a universe. Namely, let $U_\kappa(I) = Psh_\kappa(\mathcal C/I)$, where $Psh_\kappa = Fun( (-)^{op}, Set_\kappa)$ is the category of presheaves with values in $V_\kappa$, and $\mathcal C/I$ is the slice category.

But for some reason, even after Hofmann and Streicher's note, some authors have continued to use universe constructions which are more elaborate and less canonical. See, for example [Kapulkin and Lumsdaine](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2851), or [Cisinski](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/higher-categories-and-homotopical-algebra/C5509D2179302B3F3876A007815A2BBC), involving well-orderings, or choices of actions of simplicial operators. My question is: why?

**Question 1:** Is there any reason to prefer more elaborate universe constructions to Hofmann-Streicher universes?

**Question 2:** If I'm reading something like Cisinski's book above, is it safe for me to replace all occurrences of his more elaborate universes with Hofmann-Streicher universes?

To be clear -- after constructing a Hofmann-Streicher universe, you generally want to cut down to some subuniverse to study things like left/right or co/cartesian fibrations, so this is not the end of the story. That's part of why I ask -- it's conceivable that one of these later steps will depend in an essential way on the initial choice of generic universes.

Comment: The construction of the universe I usually use is the one of Hofmann-Streicher. This construction goes way back before their work though. You may find variations on it in Giraud's book "Cohomologie non abélienne" (published in 1971) but the idea can be traced back to Grothendieck's SGA1 where the Grothendieck construction is introduced and various ways to rectify 2-functors are explained out of the induced biequivalence and a 2-categpriical version of the Yoneda LemmA (SGA1 is also published in 1971 but the seminar took place in 1961, and copies of the seminar notes circulated since then).

Comment: The general construction is as follows. Say you work with sheaves on a small site $C$. Then $x\mapsto Sh(C/x)$ is a stack i.e. a sheaf with values in the $(\infty,1)$-category of categories. We can replace this stack up to equivalence by a stack $F$ so that it is also an ordinary sheaf with values in the 1-category of categories. We can then define the universe $U=Ob(F)$. The choice of $F$ is irrelevant as long as it is obtained as above. All constructions of universes in practice are explicit choices of such $F$ of which we take subsheaves.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski I'm looking at Definition 5.2.3 in your _Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra_ (from a version dated Sept 24, 2021), and it looks different from the Hofmann-Streicher universe. Are you saying that it's really the same thing in disguise?

Comment: I'm also not sure in what sense the Hofmann-Streicher universe is equivalent to the stack $[n] \mapsto Psh_\kappa(\Delta/[n])^\simeq$. It seems to me that it's a conveniently-chosen presheaf which is _not_ equivalent to this, but maps essentially surjectively to it. (and I suppose maybe that could lead to a reason not to use it... but I'm still not sure exactly what the reason would turn out to be)

Comment: Yes I mean that the version I use in my book is isomorphic. And no, I do not claim that the universe of Hofmann-Streicher is equivalent to the stack; this does not make sense because they define a sheaf of sets as opposed to a stack. What I claim is that, the only thing that matters is to choose a sheaf F with values in the 1-category of 1-categories that is equivalent to ↦ℎ(/) (as 2-functors) and to define $U$ to the be the sheaf of sets obtained as ↦Ob(F()). I claim that any such $U$ is OK. (...)

Comment: (...) It does not matter if is it is obtained by choosing well ordered structures on fibers or by the Hofmann-Streicher trick, or any other recipe.

Comment: When I say "it does not matter" I do not claim that all universes obtained this way are isomorphic (they are not) but that any of them may be used (they all will be "unique up to homotopy" in some sense and that is sufficient. Ideas about this kind of unicity are at the end of the book of Joyal and Moerdijk on Algebraic Set Theory.

Comment: In addition to @D.-C.Cisinski's point above that all three of these maps are generic for the same class of maps, all 3 behave similarly wrt what strict/1-categorical structure we can equip them with. In fact, all 3 satisfy the "realignment lemma" so they function in much the same way; we are able to obtain excellent and very strict equalities on particular codes in these universes which we need to show eg, fibrancy. (For instance, [Streicher has a note redoing the VV proof of fibrancy for the HS universe](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/sstt.pdf)).

Comment: There are a few situations in type theory where one must replace the HS universe, but these are typically due to somewhat perverse constraints. For instance, satisfying some degree of the realignment lemma constructively (the HS universe relativizes), getting certain codes to be injective, etc. But these are all sort of non-invariant properties of the particular universe and typically invisible. See, for instance [Lemma 5.9 of this pdf](https://jozefg.github.io/papers/denotational-semantics-of-general-store-and-polymorphism.pdf) or [this note](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.05529)